# Magento com Ubuntu 16.04 + Nginx+MariaDb+php7. Nao carrega a página

Tags: linux, magento, nginx

Tenho o seguinte ambiente:

Ubuntu16.04 + Nginx + MariaDb + Php7. Fiz o download do Magento através do composer:

```
composer create-project magento/community-edition magento2 -s dev --prefer-dist
```

Depois criei um banco de dados no servidor do MariaDB.

Normalmente o proximo passo seria abrir o magento e passar usuário e password do banco de dados recém criado.

Digito a URL `cb100.com` e sou redirecionado para `cb100.com/setup/`.

A resposta que tenho é uma página em branco.
O favicon da tab é do magento. Ou seja, algo está funcionando.

Quando vejo o log do NginX isso é o que tenho:

```
could not find named location "@handler", client: 127.0.0.1, server:
cb100.com, request: "POST /setup/index.php/session/prolong HTTP/1.1",
host: "cb100.com", referrer: "http://cb100.com/setup/"
```

Não tenho mais nenhuma pista

A única mudança que fiz foi na permissão das pastas do projeto. Passei todas para o grupo `www-data`. Grupo sob o qual roda o NginX.

```
chown -R ila:www-data cb100.com;
```

Será que está faltando alguma configuração no NginX?

UPDATE

Vou postar o codigo do Magento `mysite.com/index.php` e `mysite.com/setup/index.php`

**cb100.com/index.php**

```
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**cb100.com/setup/index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
echo "here";
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    echo "You cannot run this from the command line." . PHP_EOL .
        "Run \"php bin/magento\" instead." . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

// For Setup Wizard we are using our customized error handler
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require __DIR__ . '/config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Comment: Que usuário e grupo estão configurados no `nginx.conf`? E se o grupo é `www-data`, os arquivos da pasta possuem permissão suficiente? Você chegou a instalar o PHP e os módulos necessários? De uma olhada [nesse tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-magento-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/). PS: Eu percebi que você fez *cross-posting* do problema em vários sites da rede, eu costumo incluir um link para cada um deles na pergunta para facilitar a vida de outros usuários.

Comment: é, eu postei em ingles no AskUbuntu e no Magento exchange. Fiquei na dúvida se se tratava de algo especifico do magento ou do ubuntu.  Sim o meu ambiente tem todos os requerimentos do php. Instalei na mão cada um deles. Esse mesmo ambiente roda outros sites, inclusive com laravel. Eu não consegui entender o erro do log do NginX, para esse projeto com Magento.

Comment: Poste o erro e demais informações relevantes (versão de tudo, etc). Eu nunca cheguei a instalar o Magento nessa versão do Ubuntu. Mas tenho um ambiente rodando no Ubuntu 14.04 com PHP-FPM, a instalação foi bem tranquila.

Comment: Fiz um update da questao

Answer (score 0):

A pagina em Branco está no firefox?

1. Para resolver esse erro vá a: /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
2. digite `vim Layout.php`
3. vá até a linha 555 e edite o codigo $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
   deixe o assim. Note que só alterou duas chaves uma depois do ultimo ponteiro e fechou depois do ultimo cochete.
4. Caso de erro de database dentro do magento: vá a  var/www/html/magento/code/core/Mago/Install/Model/Installer/ 
   e edite o codigo db.php na linha 101 com a menssagem: 
   Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('install')->__($e->getMessage()));

Comment: Oi @Douglas, vou tentar essa sua abordagem. Mas não é no firefox somente. Eu testei no chrome tbm. Acho que não é nada ligado a browser. Acho que tem a ver com a instalação via composer. Está faltando algo que foi feito o download mas nao foi instalado.